# Cumulative count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that includes different columns. One of the columns is the name of the users (note that this not unique meaning that a name might appear at different rows) and one of the other columns is the date_time showing the time and date of logins by different users. Now, I want to build a new column showing the cumulative count of logins for each user on each day. Specifically, I want to add a new feature that tells me how many times the user logged before the current login on the same day. We should go through each row and based on the user name find the number of logins by the same user for the same day but before the current login and count them.

Could you please help me with how I can write this in the most efficient way?

The input dataframe is:

```
user  date_time
JK    2016-01-15 09:27:00
KL    2016-02-10 12:17:00
JK    2016-01-15 11:07:00
JK    2016-01-15 12:17:10
KL    2016-02-10 12:47:00
JK    2017-11-15 08:27:00
```

The output dataframe is:

```
user  date_time               cum_count
Jk    2016-01-15 09:27:00     0    
KL    2016-02-10 12:17:00     0
Jk    2016-01-15 11:07:00     1
JK    2016-01-15 12:17:10     2
KL    2016-02-10 12:47:00     1
Jk    2017-11-15 08:27:00     0
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please add an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to showcase what you intend to do exactly?

Comment: @RaghulRaj I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do `groupby` + `cumcount`

```
df.groupby([df.user,df.datetime.dt.date]).cumcount()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df['cum_count'] = df.groupby(['user', df['date_time'].dt.date]).cumcount()
#if neccesary convert to datetime
#df['cum_count'] = df.groupby(['user',
#                              pd.to_datetime(df['date_time']).dt.date]).cumcount()


  user           date_time  cum_count
0   Jk 2016-01-15 09:27:00          0
1   KL 2016-02-10 12:17:00          0
2   Jk 2016-01-15 11:07:00          1
3   JK 2016-01-15 12:17:10          0
4   KL 2016-02-10 12:47:00          1
5   Jk 2017-11-15 08:27:00          0
```

---

You need [`Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) 
if you don't want to distinguish between upper and lower case in the name of the users

```
df['cum_count'] = (df.groupby([df['user'].str.lower(), 
                               df['date_time'].dt.date]).cumcount()

  user           date_time  cum_count
0   Jk 2016-01-15 09:27:00          0
1   KL 2016-02-10 12:17:00          0
2   Jk 2016-01-15 11:07:00          1
3   JK 2016-01-15 12:17:10          2
4   KL 2016-02-10 12:47:00          1
5   Jk 2017-11-15 08:27:00          0
```

Comment: That lower case was by mistake. I modified it! You can modify your answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Pandas* grouping contains *cumcount* function, so the obvious solution
is just to use it.

And a note about grouping:

- As I see, *user* column is written with either upper or lower case
  letters, so grouping by user name should be actually by upper case of
  *user*.
- Grouping by date should be on the **normalized** date (with time part
  set to *00:00:00*).

So the code can be:

```
df['cum_count'] = df.groupby([df.user.str.upper(), df.date_time.dt.normalize()])\
    .cumcount()
```